# Flutter Radio Buttons validation

Tags: validation, flutter, radio-button

I am implementing a custom radio button with validation and values are passed in those buttons. There is a run time error which i am not able to figure out. I am getting the following error

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (10799): An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.
I/flutter (10799): This happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the
I/flutter (10799): InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a
I/flutter (10799): SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it.
I/flutter (10799): 'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart':
I/flutter (10799): Failed assertion: line 945 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity'
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter FormBuilder Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
    ),
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
MyHomePageState createState() {
return MyHomePageState();
  }
 }

 class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 var data;
 bool autoValidate = true;
 bool readOnly = false;
 bool showSegmentedControl = true;
 final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
 final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> _specifyTextFieldKey =
 GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

   ValueChanged _onChanged = (val) => print(val);
   // var genderOptions = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("FormBuilder Example"),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          FormBuilder(
            // context,
            key: _fbKey,
            autovalidate: true,
            //initialValue: {
             // 'movie_rating': 5,
           // },
            readOnly: false,
            child: Row(
              
              children: <Widget>[
                
                FormBuilderRadio(
                  
                  decoration:
                  InputDecoration(labelText: 'My chosen language'),
                  attribute: "best_language",
                  leadingInput: true,
                  onChanged: _onChanged,
                  validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                  options:
                  ["Delete", "Approve", "Revert"]
                      .map((lang) => FormBuilderFieldOption(
                    value: lang,
                    child: Text('$lang'),
                  ))
                      .toList(growable: false),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  child: Text(
                    "Submit",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_fbKey.currentState.saveAndValidate()) {
                      print(_fbKey.currentState.value);
                    } else {
                      print(_fbKey.currentState.value);
                      print("validation failed");
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  child: Text(
                    "Reset",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _fbKey.currentState.reset();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
 }
   void changeIndex() {
  setState(() {
  selectedIndex = 1;
  print("Value passed is delete");

});
}
 void changeIndex1() {
  setState(() {
  selectedIndex = 1;
  print("Value passed is a");

});
}
void changeIndex2() {
setState(() {
  selectedIndex = 1;
  print("Value passed is r");

  });
 }




 Widget customRadio1() => OutlineButton(
onPressed: () => changeIndex(),
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey),
child: Text(lst[0], style: TextStyle(
    color: selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey),),

);
 Widget customRadio2() => OutlineButton(
onPressed: () => changeIndex1(),
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
child: Text(lst[1], style: TextStyle(
    color: selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),),

);
 Widget customRadio3() {
return OutlineButton(
  onPressed: () => changeIndex2(),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
  borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.grey),
  child: Text(lst[2], style: TextStyle(
      color: selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.grey),),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `InputDecorator` cannot have an unbounded width as mentioned in the logs. The cause of this is that the InputDecorator is in a Scrollable Row and has an undefined width. To solve this issue, you can wrap the child widgets in the Row with a Container with a width configured.